# Google cloud storage - API not working it shows index.php only

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am an Android developer. I created a PHP API to communicate with my Android project. It works well in Godaddy. I want to move it to Google Cloud service. I deployed the PHP project, but it shows only the index page of my domain. It doesn't show any other PHP files. Can anyone help me ?

Do I need to add more in this `app.yaml` File?

```
runtime: php55
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: yes

    runtime_config:
        document_root: ipltrivia
    handlers:
    - url: .*
      script: index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one default handler in your `app.yaml`, and said handler only shows the `index.php` file.

You can serve other PHP scripts adding another handlers, like in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example):

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

If you also need a default handler for an empty/not recognised path, you can always add:

```
- url: /
  script: index.php
```